# Dialog remains open on accept-button click

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm building a form to get a username and password from a user and I can't get it to work. Basically when I enter in the username and password, if I hit "Cancel" or close the window it pulls the data, but when I press "Ok" it crashes. I'm sure this is a simple fix but I can't seem to find something similar on Google (which suggests there is a better way to do it... but I'm new to vb.net, haha).

Here is the form (wrapped in a public function returning the username/password in a dictionary):

```
Public Function displayLoginForm() As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim loginForm As New Form()
    Dim usernameLabel As New Label()
    Dim username As New TextBox()
    Dim passwordLabel As New Label()
    Dim password As New TextBox()
    Dim okButton As New Button()
    Dim cancelButton As New Button()

    usernameLabel.Text = "Username:"
    usernameLabel.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    usernameLabel.Width = 70
    username.Height = 20
    username.Width = 300
    username.Location = New Point(80, 10)

    passwordLabel.Text = "Password:"
    passwordLabel.Location = New Point(10, 40)
    passwordLabel.Width = 70
    password.Height = 20
    password.Width = 300
    password.Location = New Point(80, 40)

    okButton.Text = "Ok"
    okButton.Location = New Point(220, 70)

    cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    cancelButton.Location = New Point(okButton.Left + okButton.Width + 10, okButton.Top)

    loginForm.Text = "Login Form"
    loginForm.Height = 130
    loginForm.Width = 400
    loginForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
    loginForm.MaximizeBox = False
    loginForm.MinimizeBox = False
    loginForm.AcceptButton = okButton
    loginForm.CancelButton = cancelButton
    loginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

    loginForm.Controls.Add(usernameLabel)
    loginForm.Controls.Add(username)
    loginForm.Controls.Add(passwordLabel)
    loginForm.Controls.Add(password)
    loginForm.Controls.Add(okButton)
    loginForm.Controls.Add(cancelButton)

    loginForm.ShowDialog()

    Dim Result As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Result.Add("username", username.Text)
    Result.Add("password", password.Text)

    Return Result

End Function
```

Comment: You really wonder why you _" can't find something on Google "_ with a subject like _"VB.net form crashes when pressing the accept button"_?

Comment: Well obviously I didn't type that into Google. :) I've been looking for things like "Vb.net example forms" and "Vb.net login form" and what not. I wasn't really sure how to word it on Stack Overflow though - I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: A better title would be:  "Dialog remains open on accept-button click". Then there would be a good chance that this question helps other as well unlike now.

Comment: I've edited the title, thanks for the improvement.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree, the form doesn't crash (at least here). It remains opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm missing this line

```
okButton.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
```

if you add it to your code, the form will close without problems.
To be honest I don't understand why the Cancel button works.
It should have a similar line

```
cancelButton.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
```

EDIT: The cancel button has its default DialogResult property set to Cancel, I presume that leaving out the DialogResult.OK on the okButton (so it defaults to Cancel) confuses the winform manager that see an AcceptButton=okButton set with DialogResult=Cancel.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that took care of it and the explanation is appreciated.